# set parent height based on his child image height

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div that with an image in it

```css
#slideshow {
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  /*height: 125px;*/
  /*width: 100vw;*/
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img alt="c" class="rectangle__image" src="/assets/media/ads-images/shad_NiOyJ1U.png">
</div>
```

I don't want to manually set the height of the image's parent; the height of the parent container should be contingent on the height of the image, but when I write the page this way, the image fails to display.

Comment: Are you sure that the image path is correct? check your browser console

Comment: Remove `position: absolute`. Absolute positioning removes the image from the document flow and will not influence the layout of the parent.

Comment: That’s because you have the image absolutely positioned - which takes an element out of the normal layout flow, it does not affect the height of its parent any more. And since your div does not get an implicit height from anywhere else, nor has one specified, you don’t see the image at all here, because “100% height” of the zero height of its parent, is also zero.

Comment: This is an slider code snippet and the image will be more then one , then it must be absolute position

Comment: Can you please share your code with the slider?

Comment: https://codepen.io/hossein_k/pen/OJpwZyM

I want to add images to <li> instead of numbers

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `position: absolute;` from the `img` since absolute positioning removes the element from document's flow.  Also you had set `opacity` to `0`.

```css
#slideshow {
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  /*height: 125px;*/
  /*width: 100vw;*/
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 15vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img alt="c" class="rectangle__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
</div>
```

---

Pen Link - https://codepen.io/techysharnav/pen/RwpByxW

Comment: https://codepen.io/hossein_k/pen/OJpwZyM

I want to add images to <li> instead of numbers

Comment: @hosseinketabi See the updated answer, I have included a pen link.

Comment: I don't want to set `height: 350px;` to #slideshow. 
The height of the parent container should be contingent on the height of the image

Comment: @hosseinketabi I have used some JavaScript to achieve this. You can use `getBoundingClientRect` to get width and height of image, and set `#slideshow`'s dimension to it.  Please check the same pen. I have updated it.